# can i handle jbehave multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, jbehave

i have jbehave testing project , we need to handle the dependency between stories . we group the stories in different paths .

i need to run each story path on different thread ,

i do the following

```
        List<String> str1 = ....
        List<String> str2 = ....

        ExecutorService executer = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);


        Embedder emb = configuredEmbedder();                
        Embedder emb1 = configuredEmbedder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                executer.submit(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("thread 1");
                        emb.runStoriesAsPaths(str1);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                executer.submit(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("thread 2");

                        emb1.runStoriesAsPaths(str2);
                    }
                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        //

        System.out.println("All tasks submitted");


        try {
            executer.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executer.shutdown();
        System.out.println("All thread tasks completed ");
```

but it doesn't run in multi threading , it runs one after another.
is the approach is not correct, or have coding issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are trying to have two different logic one for even and one for odd... anyways please find below a working code with ExcutorService..

```
public class TestExecutorService {

     static ExecutorService executer = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public TestExecutorService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String... str1)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

             int y = i%2;

                switch (y) {

                case 0:
                    executer.submit(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("thread 1"+ "count: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 1:
                    executer.submit(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("thread 1"+ "count: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());


                        }
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: the problem with jbehave with threading not with threading itself